# How to install Python statsmodels on Apple M1?

Tags: python, statsmodels, apple-m1

I cannot figure out how to install statsmodels on my M1 machine. After following the instructions in similar threads about scipy and numpy issues with M1, I am able to install these, but cannot install statsmodels.

Statsmodels issues were also raised here, but unresolved:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13409

`python --version  Python 3.8.9`

`pip --version pip 21.3.1`

The command `pip install statsmodels==0.13.1` leads to the error message:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodels==0.13.1`

Has anyone managed to install it?

Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue and never managed to install it...

Comment: How do you handle it then? any workaround or just avoid using statsmodels?

Comment: I recoded the functions I need ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing it from `conda-forge`? This package [page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/statsmodels) shows that there's a `osx-arm64` version available.

You can install Miniforge (or Mambaforge, if you prefer) for Apple Silicon platforms from the [conda-forge GitHub repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge). Then just follow the installation instructions and create an environment to install statsmodels into.

Unfortunately, I don't have an M1 machine so I can't test if it's working.

Comment: Thank you! Although I wanted to avoid conda, this works for the time being!

Answer (score 0):

Try statsmodels 0.13.2, in which support for M1 Macs was added (https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7625)

Comment: I have tried installing this version on Apple M1, but still throws subprocess error. error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.